# Pass Multiple Keys in @Requestparam with a Single String Variable

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-restcontroller

[![In this Image I have to search person by based on dropdown selection ][1]][1]

I want to pass this selections through `@Requestparam`, I have multiple keynames but I want to pass one key at a time So, I want to use only **One String** whatever the parameter comes from the request it should fetch the key value in One String

I don't want like this
`@RequestParam(value = "pname", required = false) String pName, @RequestParam(value = "ssn", required = false) String sSN)`

I want Some thing like this (**i.e multiple keyvalues with single String Variable**)

```
    public List<Patient> getPatientListLike(@RequestParam(required = false) String searchString)
```

Answer (score 4):

You may use something like this

```
@PostMapping("/api/foos")
@ResponseBody
public String updateFoos(@RequestParam Map<String,String> allParams) {
    return "Parameters are " + allParams.entrySet();
}
curl -X POST -F 'name=abc' -F 'id=123' http://localhost:8080/api/foos
-----
Parameters are {[name=abc], [id=123]}
```

Please refer here for details https://www.baeldung.com/spring-request-param

Answer (score 0):

You may create searchString as ssn=ssnValue (ssnValue which user select on screen) in UI code and pass it to url.

Answer (score 0):

You can use HttpServletRequest request to get query string

```
public List<Patient> getPatientListLike(HttpServletRequest request) {

    String searchString = request.getQueryString();

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can modify the method to:

```
public List<Patient> getPatientListLike(
    @RequestParam(required = false) String searchString,
    @RequestParam(required = false) String searchType
)
```

`searchString` is presentation the textbox and `searchType` is presentation drop-down value.

Answer (score 0):

RequestParam also maps to object. Do not reinvent the way requests are processed and always follow best API design principles. Pass the query parameters as they are meant to, where all key value pairs are separated with ampersand.

```
GET /search?pname=name&ssn=123
```

You may have to use constructor with Jackson annotations to help marshalling it. I prefer public fields on data structures.

```
class SearchParameters {
   private String pname;
   private String ssn;
   // getters-setters
}

@GetMapping("search")
public List<Patient> getPatientListLike(SearchParameters parameters)
```

Comment: ```@GetMapping(value = "/list/search")
 public List<Patient> getPatientListLike(@RequestParam(required = false) SearchParam parameters){
  
  List<Patient> pList = patientServices.getPatientListLike1(parameters);
 return pList;
 }```




 
        i'm passing ```/search?pname=somename``` but it prints ```null``` in logs

Comment: Make the fields private and add public getters and setters then instead. Alternative solution would be to use `@JsonCreator` on the constructor and marking parameters with `@JsonProperty` annotations.

Comment: ```public class SearchParam {
 @JsonProperty
 private String pname;
 @JsonCreator
 public SearchParam(String pname) {
  this.pname = pname;
 }

 public String getPname() {
  return pname;
 }

 public void setPname(String pname) {
  this.pname = pname;
 }
}
```
check my service Implementation
```@Override
 public List<Patient> getPatientListLike1(SearchParam parameters) {
   List<Patient> patients;
  patients = patientRepository.findByName(parameters.getPname());
  return patients;
 }```
Again I'm getting same null value

Comment: Remove the @RequestParam annotation from your mapping. This cannot be used.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply replace the `String` request param with a `Map<String, String>` request param. [resource](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-request-param#mapping-all-parameters)

```
public List<Patient> getPatientListLike(@RequestParam(required = false) Map<String, String> searchParams)
```